# Globally deny access to website for update, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

This is a fairly open question as i am not sure what the best practice could/should be for this type of activity.

The scenario; A user based website (with logged in user areas and user editable content) needs to have several operations performed that will manipulate live data. To stop any errors occurring due to users simultaneously editing as the update is taking place, i need to shut out the users temporarily.

I don't currently have a config database table, just a config file. Two things need to happen;

- An update to the config happens to stop the users accessing certain areas of the website during the update - this is then reverted once the update is complete.
- The website (or at least portions on the site) need to be checked before every request for said portions of the site - so whatever the method, it needs to be lightweight

This is site built on Laravel.

Thanks!

Comment: does laravel 5 still have `php artisan down` to put it into maintenance mode?

Comment: If you are fully aware how to program then this sounds like more of a User Experience question. Please see my answer on this site to get an idea of how to hold the user's hand before and during maintenance periods. http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/65207/whats-the-most-user-friendly-way-to-inform-users-that-a-feature-is-temporarily/65209#65209

Comment: Thanks @castis and MonkeyZeus. For a little more information; this is a fantasy football league, so this downtime will happen at the end of each gameweek and will have to happen during what you could call 'peak time' (as people will be logging on to try and find out how they did as soon as possible!). Although i could pull the whole site down, it would be nice to still allow the user to portions of the site that will not be effected by the 'Update Mode'

Comment: @Alex At minimum, I think that the exact same hand-holding applies. Coding the website to only block off certain features is a beast of an undertaking as it stands.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - Thanks, that is a useful post, but all of those things go without saying really. I suppose, really i want to modify (or create my own) Maintenance mode in Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple artisan command for that. Use this to shut down the application:

```
php artisan down
```

And this to turn it back on:

```
php artisan up
```

Comment: If you read through the comments and the question itself, you will see this is not the answer i want

Answer (score 2):

I'll use serveral measures in this case.

1. put the code in try - catch block so that if something goes wrong, you can grcefully show an error message.
2. If there are mulitple executions invovled, then better use `DB::transaction()` and the system will roll back automatically if it encounters an error.
3. If you really want to put certain features on maintence mode, then put those routes in `Route::group()` and use a middleware for that group only. In that middleware, return response with 503 status. This way, you can put certain routes into maintanace mode while the rest will give 200  ok response.

Comment: Upvote for the third option. I think this is really what the OP want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks itachi; I think option 3 is also pretty close to what i am after. But how should i trigger the 503 during the maintenance mode? If it was a DB setting, i would have to perform a check against the DB for EVEY request..?